# Problem launching Flutter application on device "timeout waiting for the application to start"

Tags: android, flutter

After some time mine Flutter application stopped building on a device. I tried `flutter clean`, Invalidate Caches and Restart in Android Studio, restarting device and Android Studio, nothing helps :(. The application still builds ok on the emulator though.

the Run log:

```
Launching lib/main.dart on Mi A1 in debug mode...
Initializing gradle...
Resolving dependencies...
Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...
Built build/app/outputs/apk/debug/app-debug.apk.
Installing build/app/outputs/apk/app.apk...
timeout waiting for the application to start
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the problem. Application was installed for other users on my phone, after I uninstalled it for all users the problem disappeared.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using android studio, a simple Invalidate Caches / Restart... would do. I tried it and it work.

**Go to File > Invalidate Caches / Restart...**

Answer (score 0):

click on pubspec.yaml and click on packages get... It solved mine

Answer (score 0):

Simply wait for a while instead of cancelling multiple times. It solved the issue.